# RecyclerView on Multiple Activity

Tags: android-activity, android-recyclerview, adapter, onclicklistener

I have an app that depends heavily on recyclerview.. Each activity has different model and layout for them.. So do I need to write separate adapters for all of them.??  Or could I have a base adapter which can have on create view holder, onbind view holder which would reduce the amount of repetitive code..PS. I also need onclick listener so, I wanted to include that in the base adapter..
What is the best way?? And if I can write a base adapter please give me some code samples..
Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 0):

> Each activity has different model and layout for them.. So do I need
>   to write separate adapters for all of them

Adapters are responsible for providing views that represent items in a data set, used by the `RecyclerView`. Now if those items in your ReyclerView are same across all the Activities then you can just have a single `RecyclerView.Adapter`

> I also need onclick listener so, I wanted to include that in the base
>   adapter.. What is the best way??

You can check this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24471109/recyclerview-onclick) for detailed implementation, but I am summarizing it briefly.

```
RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler);
recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(
    new RecyclerItemClickListener(context, new RecyclerItemClickListener.OnItemClickListener() {
      @Override public void onItemClick(View view, int position) {
        // do whatever
      }
    })
);
```

And provide `RecyclerItemClickListener` class, that implements `RecyclerView.OnItemTouchListener` interface

> And if I can write a base adapter please give me some code samples.

You need to clarify what exactly needs to be implemented in BaseAdapter for anyone to help you

Answer (score 0):

yes it is possible

```
enter code here holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (modelArrayList.get(position).heading.equals("maps")){
                Intent intent = new Intent(holder.button.getContext(),MainActivity2.class);

                holder.button.getContext().startActivity(intent);

            }
            if (modelArrayList.get(position).heading.equals("calls")){
                Intent intent = new Intent(holder.button.getContext(),MainActivity3.class);

                holder.button.getContext().startActivity(intent);

            }
```

Comment: this is the code for adapterview and code starts from holder.button . if any queries are there please free to ask